# Searching in angular.js using id

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I have two json:

`all_users`

```
    "all_users":
    {
    "4":{
    "user_id":4,
    "user_name":"Miranda"
     },
    "7":{
    "user_id":7,
    "user_name":"seconduser"
    }
```

And `tickets`

```
"tickets":
[{
"ticket_id" : 12,
"created_by" : 7,
"assigned_to": 6
}]
```

Now, from the json `tickets`, I need to search who created a ticket, i.e `created_by`. But, since this is id, I am not able to search it directly using name. 
After doing my bit of research, I implemented this:

```
<input id="created-by-input" type="text" ng-model="search.created_by" placeholder="Created by" typeahead="user.user_id as user.user_name for user in transformationFunction(all_users, $viewValue) | filter:{user_name:$viewValue}"  class="form-control">
```

And the scope:

```
$scope.transformationFunction = function(object) {
    var newArray = [];
    for(var key in object) {
      newArray.push({user_id: key, user_name: object[key].user_name});
  }
  return newArray;
  console.log(newArray)
};
```

However, when I am searching, I get all the relevant users when I start typing. Also, when I click on them, the search filter works and shows me the result. But, when I click on the users in the dropdown while searching, the text field shows me the ID and not the user name.

For example: I start typing *Mira*, the dropdown shows Miranda, when I click on it, the text field shows me 4.

What am I missing out in here??

Comment: Will you please make a plunker/fiddle/codepen for us ?

Comment: Umm.. I have never made a plunker/fiddle. This is my first project in front-end

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ejf2p74g/ This is what I managed.

Answer (score 0):

If you would store your users as an array
e.g.

```
$scope.users = [{
     id: 1,
     name: "Fancyname"
 },
 {
     id: 2,
     name: "Fancyname2"
 }]
```

You could use the .map function like this:

```
var index = $scope.users.map(function(x) {return x.id; }).indexOf(idYourAreLookingFor);
var user= $scope.users[index];
```

Comment: But, unfortunately I can't store them as array.